# If input is CHECKED button ENABLE VUE JS

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, checkbox, conditional-statements

I am trying to enable the next button only when the box is checked. For this I'm trying to validate if the button is checked or not. Then once it is checked and the button is enabled when going next to the next step, and the button should be again disabled.

I am importing the Detailsform0.vue inside of ProductPage.vue through the date items:[] so each form as a separate file. Can someone help me with how to enable the button on click to checkbox and then on click next the button has to require again the same condition. Thank you in advance
[image: Screenshot]

DetailsForm0.vue
    
      
        this is a test
        I have filled all this page

```
\\\\\ ProductPage.vue 
<template>
    <component v-bind:is="currentStep.details"></component>
    <button class="btn" v-on:click="backStep" id="back">Back</button>
    <button class="btn" v-on:click="nextStep" v-bind:disabled="checked === false" id="next">Next</button>
</template> /// DetailsForm0 <template>
    <component v-bind:is="currentStep.details"></component>
    <button class="btn" v-on:click="backStep" id="back">Back</button>
    <button class="btn" v-on:click="nextStep" v-bind:disabled="checked === false" id="next">Next</button></template>

  data: function () {
    return {
      items: [
        { stepTitle: 'Step 1', details: DetailsForm0 },
        { stepTitle: 'Step 2', details: DetailsForm1 },
        { stepTitle: 'Step 3', details: DetailsForm2 },
        { stepTitle: 'Step 4', details: DetailsForm3 }
      ],
      activeNumber: 0,
      checked:false
    }
  },
```

Comment: I don't see any code regarding the checkbox. Show us that. That checkbox should also bind to the `checked` variable. Also show us the `nextStep` code, in there you should set the `checked` variable to false again.

Comment: nextStep: function () {
      this.toggleActive(this.activeNumber + 1)
      this.checked = false
    },




Yes in the nextStep i have the checed to false again. 
DetailsForm0 \\\ inside of this vue file here is the check box
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked">I have filled all this page<br>

so how do i connect them with the button

Answer (score 0):

```
     [[[ DetailsForm0.vue]]] *** The check box is coming from DetailsForm0.Vue File  here what is in the file***
<template>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked">I have filled all this page<br>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'DetailsForm',
  data: function () {
    return {
      checked: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
     [[[ ProductPage.vue]]] *** The DetailsForm0.Vue is getting imported here in ProductPage.vue File ***
    <template>
        <component v-bind:is="currentStep.details"></component>
        <button class="btn" v-on:click="backStep" id="back">Back</button>
        <button class="btn" v-on:click="nextStep" v-bind:disabled="checked === false" id="next">Next</button></template>

      data: function () {
        return {
          items: [
            { stepTitle: 'Step 1', details: DetailsForm0 },
            { stepTitle: 'Step 2', details: DetailsForm1 },
            { stepTitle: 'Step 3', details: DetailsForm2 },
            { stepTitle: 'Step 4', details: DetailsForm3 }
          ],
          activeNumber: 0,
          checked:false
        }
      },

    <script>
    methods: {
        toggleActive: function (index) {
          this.activeNumber = index
        },
        nextStep: function () {
          this.toggleActive(this.activeNumber + 1)
          this.checked = false
        }
        }
```